# Factory or DI suitable for inheritance

Tags: c#, design-patterns, ooad

I have different kinds of Quotes, like Boat quote, Motorcycle quote, CarQuote which all derive from Quote class. When a client wants to get quote I need to just return Quote.
I can implement in two ways:

Factory:

```
public class QuoteFactory{
     public Quote GetQuote(string QuoteType )
     {
      if(quoteType = "car")
         {
           return new CarQuote()
        }
     }
```

DI with Spring.Core

Add all the quote types to Context and then let client decides which type is needed. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use the one that satisfies your needs, and you've only outlined one which you seem to think can be satisfied with both approaches. You haven't provided any code for the DI case, and I'm not sure how you would implement this with DI. If they both satisfy your needs, flip a coin and refactor later if you find your design hampers testability or whatever.

Comment: Are you just boasting or is there a question?

Comment: @itsme86 I think it's "should I use a factory or DI?" Still, not a very good question since either the two do the same and the choice is arbitrary lacking other requirements, or only one of them will work and the choice is obvious. (Or the OP expects us to give him a rundown of the nonfunctional design constraints in which case my magic eight ball says the outlook isn't great since SO isn't much for architecture astronaut monologues these days.)

Comment: @itsme, just consider me a new guy learning learning design patterns :)

Comment: In that case, may I suggest a book? Besides, it's not like design patterns have zero overlap when it comes to the problems they solve. The current groupthink is that SO isn't a teaching site, and "What is the best way to do X?" questions lacking any other constraints fare poorly. Especially since that means there's no context to your question, and a "real-world" solution might in fact be several factories, each injected where it's needed. (So the module that sells cars would get a `CarQuoteFactory` etc.) Or it might not, it's not easy to tell without context.

Comment: Millimoose, Can I use DI in case of Inheritance? I will try to Google more. The real world problem is "Get a Quote where a quote can be of 20 different types. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Ron Maybe? The context I mean is how is it determined what type of quote you need. Do you need it to be selected dynamically based on user input - in which case I'd use a registry of factories? Do you need different modules of your app to be more or less statically tied to a quote type? Then you can inject factories into those modules. I don't think a single factory parametrised the way it is in your code sample is at all helpful though.

Comment: @Ron The way DI fits into the picture here is for the purposes of *wiring things up*. That is, the DI container can either gather all available factory implementations and inject them all into a registry that can select them based on user input. **Or** it can connect modules of your app to the appropriate quote provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the point of that method if all you require is a quote. The calling method knows what type of quote it wants - it has to as your passing it in as parameter. If you genuinely want to abstract the creation of the quote into an injectable class (for unit testing for example) why not create a generic method eg:

```
public class QuoteFactory : IQuoteFactory
{
    public TQuote CreateQuote<TQuote>()
        where TQuote : new() // or Quote if specific attributes requied to be set by factory
    {
        return new TQuote();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks VegDork, I read about TQuote style somewhere before also and I think this is what probably I will go for.

Comment: Of course this is the exact opposite of abstracting quote creation (which is what a factory is supposed to do), since all it can do is create different subtypes of the quote, just in the exact same way. It'd be more useful as a base class for quote factories where the subclasses then initialise the type-specific properties.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your question, but this is the refactored factory using DI:

```
public class QuoteFactory : IQuoteFactory{
    public QuoteFactory(Quote boatQ, Quote motorQ, Quote carQ){
        // parameter assignment
    }
    Quote boatQ;
    Quote motorQ;
    Quote carQ;

    public Quote Create(string quote){
        if(quote == "car") return carQ;
        //further condition
    }
}
```

Using this design you can depend on DI Container to handle the constructor injections. Moreover, you can replace this design by injecting `IDictionary<string, Quote>` instead.